# Maatwebsite excel global transaction problems

Tags: php, transactions, locking, maatwebsite-excel

in my PHP application, I am using the Maatwebsite excel library to process excel sheets. I am facing problems with locking on the database and think that this library is not releasing the locks and the "DEALOCATE prepare_statement" is hanging on my database so the locks are there (most probably due to transactions not being finalized correctly).

To my knowledge and research, I found that the Maatwebsite excel library wraps automatically each execution with a transaction, so all the transaction blocks in the import excel code are not taken into consideration as it is the overall transaction that is taken into consideration. But I am unable to remove the wrapping transaction from some sheets.

In some cases i want to manage the transactions myself, is there a way to disable the global transaction for some sheets?

Comment: To give us a starting point, as per the [ask] guide please provide a [mre] of your issue, then we can see precisely what you're doing and have a better chance of verifying the root cause.  20 lines of code can often say more than 1000 words ever can. Thanks.